# groovy grails async promise execute immediately

Tags: java, grails, groovy, promise

In the below code, inside **controllerMethod** ,  onComplete event execute immediately without waiting for the finishing of **promiseList** in the callApisInParallel method in groovy/grails

```
import grails.async.Promise
import grails.async.PromiseList

class asyncProgram {

    def getReportTask() {

        return task {

            def res = reportService.fetchReport()
            // api request
            res
        }
    }

    private def callApisInParallel() {

        def promiseList = new PromiseList()

        def reportTask = getReportTask()
        promiseList << reportTask

        //def apiResults = waitAll(promiseList)
        //def results = apiResults[0]
        // def res = results[0]

        promiseList

    }

    def execute() {


        Promise p = task {

            def promiseList = callApisInParallel()

           promiseList.onComplete { result ->
                println "Promise returned $result"

                //manipulate the data and then return the result

                //resolve()
            }

        }

        return p
    }

    def controllerMethod() {

        Promise p = execute()
        p.onComplete { result ->

        }
    }

}
```

I need something like "resolve" method in javascript which can tells the onComplete event of **execute** method that the onComplete is done and mark the current promise complete

I found one link 
[Groovy/Grails promises/futures. There is no .resolve(1,2,3) method. Strange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535410/groovy-grails-promises-futures-there-is-no-resolve1-2-3-method-strange)
but I am not able to understand in the above approach properly

Comment: How is the question related to JS and Node?

Comment: This is the question related to groovy/ grails who also have knowledge on nodejs promise. 
They can understand the concept from javascript and use the same on groovy

Comment: Promises aren't specific to Node. It's language-agnostic pattern, there's separate `promise` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a promiseList with task here:

```
def promiseList = callApisInParallel()
```

then why are you not using it here?

```
p.onComplete { result ->
println "Promise returned $result"

//manipulate the data and then return the result

//resolve()
}
```

Change `p.onComplete` to `promiseList.onComplete`

Comment: I will be doing some business logic promiseList.onComplete { result -> println "Promise returned $result" //manipulate the data and then return the result //resolve() } here and then pass on to the result once done. The next method will use the result returned by this method